# How to remove the letter before chapter appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, letters

I want to remove the letter at the beginning of the appendix chapter. I use a .cls style formatting file.
My code produces the following table of contents:

[image]

I would like to get:

[image]

my `.cls` code is:

```
\def\appendix{%  
\setcounter{chapter}{0}%  
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%  
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\appendixname}}
```

How can I change the code to get the result I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your fragment of code is not really useful. We need more information on the class and a minimal document that is compilable and has this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that you are using `book` class.  It has the following definition:

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

Let the macro `\appendix` redefine it, adding to the TOC just the chapter name, but not its number:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\def\appendix{%
  \def\@chapter[##1]##2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                       \fi
                       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{##1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{##1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{##2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{##2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}%
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}%  
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\appendixname}}  
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{second}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Aaaa}

\end{document}
```

[image]